# ImportError: No module named cv

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, simplecv

I get this error on running SimpleCV:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/SimpleCV/base.py", line 22, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
```

What could be going wrong? Please suggest..

Comment: Well, where is the cv module?

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI SimpleCV has a help forum at help.simplecv.org. It looks like python doesn't know where the opencv packages got installed. Doing a sudo easy_install probably won't work. What you need to do is figure out where the cv libraries live on your system, and where python is looking for them and then symbolically linking the two.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I just set up the environment to study SimpleCV and write the blog to record the steps as [SimpleCV environment setup on Mac](http://brownydev.blogspot.tw/2012/11/simplecv-environment-setup-on-mac.html). Maybe it could help you :)